# CDI Beans and JPA Transactions

Tags: java, jpa, cdi

Shall a bean which is for instance used as cdi application scoped contain jpa read/write stuff or should I use always EJB for db stuff? I read somewhere on the internet that cdi shall not contain db stuff. Is that true?

Comment: Generally, a single sentence does not make a good question on the internet. Can you add some context into the question?

Comment: ok i added more, please take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always the answer is it depends... It depends on your specific use case.

In Java EE we use `@EJB` beans as the place where we Inject the `EntityManager` to later perform read/write on JPA Entities. 
Why we do this? Because we need `Transactions`. By default when you annotate a bean with `@Stateless` all the methods in it are `Transactional` and you get it all for free. Transactions enable you to update multiple tables in an atomic fashion, they will either succeed all or fail.

Example:
In your method  `updateABC()`you want to update Table A,B,C and you want all of them to succeed or the transaction to be Roll-backed:

```
@Stateless
public class MyClass{
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public void updateABC(){
       A a= em.find(A.class, aId);
       //here update some fields on the entity "a"

       B b= em.find(B.class, bId);
       //here update some fields on the entity "b"
       C c= em.find(C.class, cId);
       //here update some fields on the entity "c"
    }
}
```

And this is it... you're done. All your updates will be magically persisted to the DB or nothing.

Do you need something like this? Go for EJB's. 
You need not? You want to do the job manually? then create your own beans...

Comment: But I i like more cdi and not ejb.. ist here way to do the same using cdi??

Comment: What do you mean by you like more CDI than EJB? They serve different purposes. In your use-case EJB is the right technology. Sure you can do it yourself in a CDI bean but you would need to implement manually the transctions boundaries, which means you will manually turn your CDI in an EJB... If you fancy to do this go on.

Comment: what purpose do cdi serve?

Comment: CDI has many capabilities (depending on the version of CDI you use). However the basic one are: Powerful and Type Safe DI(Dependency Injection), Interceptors, Decorators, Events etc. However EJBs have additional capabilities. Read this blog post, it might clarify some ideas: http://blog.dblevins.com/2012/11/cdi-when-to-break-out-ejbs.html

Comment: @Alboz : you can use CDI without managing transaction, using the  `@Transactional` InterceptorBinding.

Comment: @Rouliboy Sure using UserTransaction and managing it yourself. Which means essentially implementing what the EJB proxy does in this case. Isn't this what I'm saying?

Comment: @Alboz : no. Using `@Transactional` InterceptorBinding, you have nothing to do more. Just annotate your method (on beans managed by container) and that's all. It's an alternative to EJB  Transaction management. And you dont have to manage UseTransaction, this is what the interceptor dors.

Answer (score 8):

YES, you can manage db stuffs on CDI beans using **`@Transactional`** InterceptorBinding if you are on any JavaEE  7 **plus** editions or **JakartaEE**

Take a look at the Javadoc : [@Transactional](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/transaction/Transactional.html)

Here are the steps to inject `EntityManager` with `CDI` without `EJB`

1. First create a producer to produce the `EntityManager`.

   ```
   public class EntityManagerProducer {
     @PersistenceContext(name = "customer-orders-unit")    
     private EntityManager em;

     @Produces
     @RequestScoped
     public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
       return em;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create your bean to do DAO actions.

   ```
   public MyCDIBeanDao{
     @Inject
     private EntityManager m_entityManager;

     @Transactional
     public doStuff(){
       // Here you are in a Container managed Transaction
       m_entityManager.persist(...)
     }
   }
   ```
3. Don't forget to add `beans.xml` in your `WEB-INF` folder.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd" 
          bean-discovery-mode="all" 
          version="2.0">
   </beans>
   ```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to the OP's question.